# How can I compactly store a shared configuration with Kubernetes Kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, tensorflow-serving, kustomize

First, I'm not sure this question is specific enough for Stack Overflow. Happy to remove or revise if someone has any suggestions.

We use Kubernetes to orchestrate our server side code, and have recently begun using Kustomize to modularize the code.

Most of our backend services fit nicely into that data model. For our main transactional system we have a base configuration that we overlay with tweaks for our development, staging, and different production flavors. This works really well and has helped us clean things up a ton.

We also use TensorFlow Serving to deploy machine learning models, each of which is trained and at this point deployed for each of our many clients. The only way that these configurations differ is in the name and metadata annotations (e.g., we might have one called `classifier-acme` and another one called `classifier-bigcorp`), and the bundle of weights that are pulled from our blob storage (e.g., one would pull from `storage://models/acme/classifier` and another would pull from `storage://models/bigcorp/classifier`). We also assign different namespaces to segregate between development, production, etc.

From what I understand of the Kustomize system, we would need to have a different base and set of overlays for every one of our customers if we wanted to encode the entire state of our current cluster in Kustomize files. This seems like a huge number of directories as we have many customers. If we have 100 customers and five different elopement environments, that's 500 directories with a `kustomize.yml` file.

Is there a tool or technique to encode this repeating with Kustomize? Or is there another tool that will work to help us generate Kubernetes configurations in a more systematic and compact way?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more complex overlay structures than just a straight matrix approach. So like for one app have `apps/foo-base` and then `apps/foo-dev` and `apps/foo-prod` which both have `../foo-base` in their bases and then those in turn are pulled in by the `overlays/us-prod` and `overlays/eu-prod` and whatnot.

But if every combo of customer and environment really does need its own setting then you might indeed end up with a lot of overlays.

Comment: That's more or less the path we started down before realizing there would be an explosion of directories with tiny two-line files. I was hoping there might be a tool we hadn't thought of that abstracts this to another level, almost.

Comment: You can also write a custom generator plugin if you could do it procedurally.

Comment: I had roughly that idea — has no one else already done something like that? That's partly what I was asking with his question. This doesn't seem like an especially exotic requirement. Perhaps I'm naïve.

Comment: Most people don't need a full overlay for each customer, so they only end up with 4 or 5 and just manage it by hand. We crammed all our per-customer logic into an operator instead.